# JMeter: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, jmeter

I am running a JMeter test with "Java Request" sampler which performs POST request to HTTPS service which uses TLS v1.2. The request fails with

```
2015/12/01 19:11:50 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.AbstractJavaSamplerClient: 2015-12-01T16:11:50.189Z message:**** Exception in JMeter node for Login java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to getServerToken
    at com.chrysler.loadtest.GUIMimicLogin.getServerToken(GUIMimicLogin.java:227)
    at com.chrysler.loadtest.GUIMimicLogin.runTest(GUIMimicLogin.java:97)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.sample(JavaSampler.java:191)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.chrysler.loadtest.GUIMimicLogin.getServerToken(GUIMimicLogin.java:215)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

JMeter used to work with this server when it used TLS v1.1. Is there a setting in JMeter properties which can set the applicable protocol.

The JMeter version is 2.13, Java version is 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

This is an SSL error and can mean several things.  Make sure you have TLS 1.2 enabled in your application (JVM argument?)(-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2).  You can use openssl to check the connection and see if you are getting back a certificate.  If you are then check your keystore and make sure you have the correct certificate.  You may not be authorized to access that server.